# How to simulate ripple effect and execute onPressed of button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to mimic the behavior of tapping with ripple on a MaterialButton in Flutter. In essence I would like to be able to call some arbitrary function (e.g. `tapTargetWithEffect(GlobalKey target)`) and see ripple effect on the button with given `GlobalKey` as well the `onPressed` callback to be executed.

I see in the pointer tests that it's possible to dispatch pointer events through `WidgetsBinding` to trigger ripple effect. How to execute the `onPressed` callbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the naive implementation how this effect can be achieved.

1. First, find the RenderBox assigned to the given GlobalKey
2. Then check if it's a button in a semantic sense (i.e. it's possible to press/tap)
3. Execute hit test on the RenderBox to get list of widgets (`HitTestEntry` objects) under given pointer position
4. Find targets that have `onTap` callbacks assigned (these will implement `RenderSemanticsGestureHandler`), take first and assign to `tappable`
5. Find targets that have `onPointerDown` callbacks assigned (these will implement `RenderPointerListener`), take first and assign to `clickable`
6. Call the `onTap` callback to execute button's `onPressed`
7. Call the `onPointerDown` with proper `PointerDownEvent` to show ripple

   1. `PointerDownEvent` accepts `position` argument, make it center of the original `RenderBox`
8. Cancel the `PointerDownEvent` after desired Duration by dispatching `PointerMoveEvent` somewhere within the app boundaries via `WidgetsBinding.instance.dispatchEvent`

   1. You'll have to execute hit test before that

Notice that `hitTest()` function accepts `BoxHitTestResult` which will contain result of the hit test :)

[image]

Sample implementation:

```dart
  void tapTargetWithEffect(GlobalKey target) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = target.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final child = renderBox as RenderSemanticsAnnotations;
    if (child.button) {
      final size = renderBox.size;
      final center = renderBox.localToGlobal(size.center(Offset.zero));
      final hitResult = BoxHitTestResult();
      child.hitTest(hitResult, position: size.center(Offset.zero));
      final pointerDown = PointerDownEvent(
        position: center,
      );
      final tappableL = hitResult.path
          .where((element) => element.target is RenderSemanticsGestureHandler)
          .map((element) => element.target as RenderSemanticsGestureHandler)
          .toList();
      final clickableL = hitResult.path
          .where((element) => element.target is RenderPointerListener)
          .map((e) => e.target as RenderPointerListener)
          .toList();

      if (tappableL.isEmpty) {
        print('No RenderSemanticsGestureHandler available');
        return;
      }

      if (clickableL.isEmpty) {
        print('No RenderPointerListener available');
        return;
      }

      final tappable = tappableL.first;
      final clickable = clickableL.first;
      clickable.onPointerDown?.call(pointerDown);
      tappable.onTap?.call();

      // cancel the pointer down event
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then((value) {
        print('Cancelling the pointer down event');
        final result = BoxHitTestResult();
        WidgetsBinding.instance.hitTest(result, Offset.zero);
        WidgetsBinding.instance.dispatchEvent(PointerMoveEvent(), result);
      });
    }
  }
```